# Iframe in Firefox with Spring Security

Tags: spring, firefox, iframe, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security and this is my configuration:

```
http
    .headers()
    .addHeaderWriter(
            new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(new WhiteListedAllowFromStrategy(Arrays.asList("https://xxx.salesforce.com"))))
```

Inside SF I have set up a new page where I'm opening my application in iframe. 
When I go to https://xxx.salesforce.com and try to open that page it in Chrome and Safari it works fine, but for some reason it does not work in Firefox.

I tried starting Firefox in Safe mode, disabling all add-ons, clearing cache, but always getting blank screen and without any error in developer console. I also tried turning fire-bug, but also error console is empty. 
My application runs on HTTPS.

What is proper configuration in Spring Security?

Comment: Too few information to troubleshoot and help. First of all - why you think it has something to do with Spring Security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was to disable security headers.

```
            .headers()
                .disable()
```

Answer (score 1):

if it´s working on chrome but not on firefox it´s obviously something wrong regarding firefox and not in Spring security. I recommend you to read this https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/737230